# Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() ViewsData.php

Tags: 9

On my drupal 9 website I get a warning when running the Cache Clear Command. I get these two messages. I have no clue where to start with finding the problem. Hope someone understands these messages and can point me in te right direction.

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Drupal\views\ViewsData->getData() (line 239 of core/modules/views/src/ViewsData.php).
Drupal\views\ViewsData->getData() (Line: 154)
Drupal\views\ViewsData->get('block_content') (Line: 91)
Drupal\views\Plugin\Derivative\ViewsEntityRow->getDerivativeDefinitions(Array) (Line: 101)
Drupal\Component\Plugin\Discovery\DerivativeDiscoveryDecorator->getDerivatives(Array) (Line: 87)
Drupal\Component\Plugin\Discovery\DerivativeDiscoveryDecorator->getDefinitions() (Line: 285)
Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->findDefinitions() (Line: 175)
Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->getDefinitions() (Line: 22)
Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->getDefinition('data_field') (Line: 16)
Drupal\Core\Plugin\Factory\ContainerFactory->createInstance('data_field', Array) (Line: 83)
Drupal\Component\Plugin\PluginManagerBase->createInstance('data_field') (Line: 817)
Drupal\views\Plugin\views\display\DisplayPluginBase->getPlugin('row') (Line: 122)
Drupal\views\Plugin\views\style\StylePluginBase->init(Object, Object, Array) (Line: 820)
Drupal\views\Plugin\views\display\DisplayPluginBase->getPlugin('style') (Line: 346)
Drupal\rest\Plugin\views\display\RestExport->collectRoutes(Object) (Line: 120)
Drupal\views\EventSubscriber\RouteSubscriber->routes()
call_user_func(Array) (Line: 146)
Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteBuilder->rebuild() (Line: 83)
Drupal\Core\ProxyClass\Routing\RouteBuilder->rebuild() (Line: 382)
Drupal\Core\Extension\ModuleInstaller->install(Array, 1) (Line: 83)
Drupal\Core\ProxyClass\Extension\ModuleInstaller->install(Array) (Line: 476)
Drupal\system\Form\ModulesListForm->submitForm(Array, Object)
call_user_func_array(Array, Array) (Line: 114)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormSubmitter->executeSubmitHandlers(Array, Object) (Line: 52)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormSubmitter->doSubmitForm(Array, Object) (Line: 592)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->processForm('system_modules', Array, Object) (Line: 320)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->buildForm(Object, Object) (Line: 73)
Drupal\Core\Controller\FormController->getContentResult(Object, Object)
call_user_func_array(Array, Array) (Line: 123)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\{closure}() (Line: 564)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext(Object, Object) (Line: 124)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->wrapControllerExecutionInRenderContext(Array, Array) (Line: 97)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\{closure}() (Line: 158)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object, 1) (Line: 80)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 58)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 48)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 106)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 85)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 48)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 51)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 23)
Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 708)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object) (Line: 19)

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Drupal\Component\Utility\NestedArray::mergeDeepArray() (line 327 of core/lib/Drupal/Component/Utility/NestedArray.php).
Drupal\Component\Utility\NestedArray::mergeDeepArray(Array) (Line: 295)
Drupal\Component\Utility\NestedArray::mergeDeep(Array, NULL) (Line: 244)
Drupal\views\ViewsData->getData() (Line: 154)
Drupal\views\ViewsData->get('block_content') (Line: 91)
Drupal\views\Plugin\Derivative\ViewsEntityRow->getDerivativeDefinitions(Array) (Line: 101)
Drupal\Component\Plugin\Discovery\DerivativeDiscoveryDecorator->getDerivatives(Array) (Line: 87)
Drupal\Component\Plugin\Discovery\DerivativeDiscoveryDecorator->getDefinitions() (Line: 285)
Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->findDefinitions() (Line: 175)
Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->getDefinitions() (Line: 22)
Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->getDefinition('data_field') (Line: 16)
Drupal\Core\Plugin\Factory\ContainerFactory->createInstance('data_field', Array) (Line: 83)
Drupal\Component\Plugin\PluginManagerBase->createInstance('data_field') (Line: 817)
Drupal\views\Plugin\views\display\DisplayPluginBase->getPlugin('row') (Line: 122)
Drupal\views\Plugin\views\style\StylePluginBase->init(Object, Object, Array) (Line: 820)
Drupal\views\Plugin\views\display\DisplayPluginBase->getPlugin('style') (Line: 346)
Drupal\rest\Plugin\views\display\RestExport->collectRoutes(Object) (Line: 120)
Drupal\views\EventSubscriber\RouteSubscriber->routes()
call_user_func(Array) (Line: 146)
Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteBuilder->rebuild() (Line: 83)
Drupal\Core\ProxyClass\Routing\RouteBuilder->rebuild() (Line: 382)
Drupal\Core\Extension\ModuleInstaller->install(Array, 1) (Line: 83)
Drupal\Core\ProxyClass\Extension\ModuleInstaller->install(Array) (Line: 476)
Drupal\system\Form\ModulesListForm->submitForm(Array, Object)
call_user_func_array(Array, Array) (Line: 114)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormSubmitter->executeSubmitHandlers(Array, Object) (Line: 52)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormSubmitter->doSubmitForm(Array, Object) (Line: 592)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->processForm('system_modules', Array, Object) (Line: 320)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->buildForm(Object, Object) (Line: 73)
Drupal\Core\Controller\FormController->getContentResult(Object, Object)
call_user_func_array(Array, Array) (Line: 123)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\{closure}() (Line: 564)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext(Object, Object) (Line: 124)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->wrapControllerExecutionInRenderContext(Array, Array) (Line: 97)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\{closure}() (Line: 158)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object, 1) (Line: 80)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 58)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 48)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 106)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 85)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 48)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 51)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 23)
Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 708)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object) (Line: 19)
```

Comment: The cache clear invalidates all views data so that every hook_views_data is invoked. One of them, probably in a custom module, is not returning a proper views data array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to 4k4s comment:

> "The cache clear invalidates all views data so that every
> hook_views_data is invoked. One of them, probably in a custom module,
> is not returning a proper views data array."

I searched my project for `_views_data` and found out I still had the Draggableviews module installed. I remember having problems with this module before and therefore don't use it anymore, it was quite easy to uninstall and remove from my project. Doing this was the solution for my problem.